# Why my lambda inside vpc can be accessed by lambda from outside vpc?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-vpc

I have created a VPC in AWS. It is a private network and no one from internet has access to this VPC. Then I put my lambda inside this VPC. After that, I found I can invoke my lambda from another lambda outside `VPC`. And I can also invoke the lambda from my local laptop.

Is this intended?

Comment: Does your Lambda function need to access a resource in the VPC? If not, then do not attach it to a VPC.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Lambda functions are not placed "into" a VPC. Rather, they *connect* to a VPC via an Elastic Network Interface (ENI).

The **AWS Lambda service** itself runs outside of the VPC (in containers on AWS servers). To invoke an AWS Lambda function, you send an API request to the AWS Lambda service, and the endpoint for that API is on the public Internet. However, when the Lambda function runs, it is connected to the VPC and is *not* connected to the Internet.

It is similar to Amazon EC2 - you can request an EC2 instance from the **Amazon EC2 Service** that is accessible on the Internet, but the EC2 instance itself only communicates with a VPC.

Comment: so there is no limitation for resources inside a private VPC subnet to call a lambda function as long as they have invokFunction permission?

Comment: For resources _inside_ a VPC to **invoke** a Lambda function, they need to have access to the Internet. This is because the API Endpoint used to communicate with the AWS Lambda service is on the Internet. Thus, if the VPC does not have an Internet Gateway, then resources in the VPC cannot 'directly' call Lambda. But, there might be alternate methods, such as pushing a message to Amazon SQS or Amazon SNS via a VPC Endpoint. Both of those services can trigger a Lambda function on your behalf.

Comment: Can a lambda have access to internet if I attach a private ENI on it?

Comment: If an AWS Lambda function is attached to a VPC, it must be attached to a private subnet. It can only gain Internet access if there is a NAT Gateway or NAT Instance in the Public Subnet.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, because you invoke lambda by connecting to [AWS public endpoint for the AWS lambda](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/lambda-service.html). Thus as long as your laptop and the function outside of the VPC have internet connection and permissions to invoke your function in the VPC, you will be able to invoke it.

"Placing" a [lambda function into VPC](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-vpc.html) does not make it "private". Instead, it allows your function to access private resources in the VPC, such as database in RDS.

Comment: Does this mean all lambdas have access to internet? Is there a way to restrict lambdas can not access resources in the internet?

Comment: @JoeyYiZhao If you "place" lambda into a VPC, it will not have internet access. Otherwise, you can't restrict it.